# Having trouble with Echo

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute the following code for 2-iterations but for first iteration, I am getting wrong result.

I run the following command:
./test.sh 2

```
# File name: test.sh

Y=`echo "$1 - 1" | bc -l`

dsp=(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 )
file1=(0 0 0 0 0 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3 -6 -6 -6 -6 -6 )

for i in {0..$Y}
    do
        a=$dsp[$i]
        e=$file1[$i]
        echo "set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y$(echo "18*${i}+ 0 + $a" | bc)   [get_cells {name[$(echo "13*${i}+0 + $e" | bc)].dut}];"
    done
```

Expected result:

```
set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y0   [get_cells {name[0].dut}]
set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y18   [get_cells {name[13].dut}]
```

But instead I am getting an error:

```
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y   [get_cells {name[].dut}];
set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y18   [get_cells {name[13].dut}];
```

Comment: Why did you use `-l` opt for `bc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables don't work inside of curly braces. To loop over a range of numbers use a C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i < Y; i++)); do
    ...
done
```

You also don't have to use `bc`. Bash can do integer arithmetic natively with `$((...))`.

```
Y=$(($1 - 1))

...

echo "set_property LOC DSP48E2_X0Y$((18*i+a))   [get_cells {name[$((13*i+e))].dut}];"
```

Also, accessing array elements requires curly braces:

```
a=${dsp[$i]}
e=${file1[$i]}
```